# Keeping duplicates based on specific rows in R in tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following data:

```
ID  Group   Interv  Book
1   Y1  G   N
1   Z1  G   B
2   Y2  G   B
2   Z2  G   B
3   Y1  G   B
3   Z1  G   B
4   Y1  G   N
5   Y2  G   B
5   Z2  G   B
6   Z1  G   B
6   Y1  G   B
7   Z1  G   B
7   Y1  G   B
8   Z1  N   B
8   Y1  N   B
9   Z1  N   B
9   Y1  N   B
10  Z1  N   B
10  Y1  N   B
11  Z1  N   B
11  Y1  N   B
12  Z1  N   B
13  Y1  G   N
```

I want to get the following table:

```
ID  Group   Room    Book
2   Y2  G   B
2   Z2  G   B
3   Y1  G   B
3   Z1  G   B
5   Y2  G   B
5   Z2  G   B
6   Z1  G   B
6   Y1  G   B
7   Z1  G   B
7   Y1  G   B
```

As you can see from  table 2, I want to keep the IDs that they have both (Y1 Z1) and (Y2 Z2) given that Interv are G and book are B. 
I have tried `filter` in tidyverse, but I was unsuccessful to get table 2.

Comment: What do you mean by *"that they have both (Y1 Z1) and (Y2 Z2)"*? From you result, maybe you mean "*that they have either (Y1 and Z1) OR (Y2 and Z2)*"? Or do you not care about `Group` as long as all `Interv` are `G` and all `Book` are `B`? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a double `filter` after grouping by "ID".  First `filter` for rows where Book is "B" and Interv is "G".  Then look for "ID"s having either `all` the "Y1", "Z1" in Group or "Y2", "Z2" in Group (as @Gregor mentioned in the comments)

```
df1 %>%
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 filter(Book == "B", Interv == "G") %>%
 filter(all(c("Y1", "Z1") %in% Group)| all(c("Y2", "Z2") %in% Group))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   ID [5]
#      ID Group Interv Book 
#   <int> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
# 1     2 Y2    G      B    
# 2     2 Z2    G      B    
# 3     3 Y1    G      B    
# 4     3 Z1    G      B    
# 5     5 Y2    G      B    
# 6     5 Z2    G      B    
# 7     6 Z1    G      B    
# 8     6 Y1    G      B    
# 9     7 Z1    G      B    
#10     7 Y1    G      B
```

Or we an do

```
df1 %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 filter(all(c("Y1", "Z1") %in% Group[Book == "B" & Interv == "G"])| 
           all(c("Y2", "Z2") %in% Group[Book == "B" & Interv == "G"]))
```

The repeated expression can be created earlier and then evaluated

```
expr <- quo(Book == "B" & Interv == "G")
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   filter(all(c("Y1", "Z1") %in% Group[!!expr])| 
          all(c("Y2", "Z2") %in% Group[!!expr]))
```

Comment: @user3546966  Please update your post with data that shows that issue

Comment: @user3546966  I changed it to `13 Y1 G B` and still don't the last row with my first solution.  What is your point?

Comment: Now, you can check the second solution as well